stack smashing detected on function return
I have function for reading TCP packet of unknown size. The function uses MSG_PEEK to find the required size for the received JSON message (the \"} in the loop condition) and then runs the loop one more time without MSG_PEEK to clean the buffer. For some reason, the two prints at the end of the function work perfectly fine, but when I call the fn, my program dies instantly after the return and prints "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated". The content_buffer shouldn't overflow, cause I'm allocating content_size + 1 and passing content_size into the recv right?
char *read_socket_raw(int socket)
{
    if (socket == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Reading socket failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *content_buffer = NULL;
    unsigned short content_size;

    why2_bool empty_buffer = 0; //WHETHER MSG_PEEK SHOULD BE USER OR NOT

    do
    {
        //FIND THE SENT SIZE
        content_size = 0;
        if (ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &content_size) < 0 || content_size <= 0) continue;

        //ALLOCATE
        content_buffer = realloc(content_buffer, content_size + 1);

        read_section:

        //READ JSON MESSAGE
        if (recv(socket, content_buffer, content_size, !empty_buffer ? MSG_PEEK : 0) != content_size) //READ THE MESSAGE BY CHARACTERS
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Socket probably read wrongly!\n");
        }

        if (empty_buffer) goto return_section; //STOP LOOPING
    } while (content_buffer == NULL || strncmp(content_buffer + (content_size - 2), "\"}", 2) != 0);

    //REMOVE JUNK FROM BUFFER (CUZ THE MSG_PEEK FLAG)
    empty_buffer = 1;
    goto read_section;

    return_section:

    content_buffer[content_size] = '\0';

    printf("'%s'\n", content_buffer);
    printf("'%p'\n\n", content_buffer);

    return content_buffer;
}


What is why2_realloc? Please show a [mre]. Sidenote: Your use of goto makes the program hard to follow. Try to avoid jumping into loops from the outside etc.

If the ioctl call fails or content_size <= 0 you'll exit the loop and re-enter it  (with goto read_section;) without allocating a buffer. boom

Im sorry, you can pass standard realloc as well. My version of realloc only uses my garbage collector. :)

"you can pass standard realloc as well" - It's better that you provide a [mre]. If everyone who reads the question has to do it, there will be many different versions of the program.

Also see my second comment that points out one possible way to get a crash.

You don't have to know how many bytes are available before you read.  Especially so if you're just going to keep reading until you get all the data you want -- you might as well just perform a blocking read. Note well that such a read may transfer fewer bytes than requested, and generally will do if it can transfer at least one byte without blocking, but not the full number requested.

Do note, however, that your approach is fragile. TCP has no built-in message boundaries, so you will likely have trouble if JSON messages are received close enough together that you don't clear one before the beginning of the next lands in the receive queue.

I'm not averse to the occasional clarifying use of goto, but using goto to jump into a loop from outside is perverse.  Obfuscating rather than clarifying.

TCP packets do not exist, TCP is a stream. Even if the sender send TCP in pieces, they can arrive as 1 piece or split at any place. So use a buffer and read up to sizeof(buffer) bytes. The result tells, how many bytes you received or if an error occurred. Functions select() and poll() can be used to check, if there any data waiting.

There is much to dislike about your function, but the one thing that seems downright incorrect is the type of variable content_size. The FIONREAD ioctl expects a pointer to int, but you've provided a pointer to unsigned short, instead.  Undefined behavior results.
In practice, your unsigned short is likely smaller than int, in which case ioctl() will presumably attempt to write past the bounds of that object. This is just the sort of thing that might trigger a stack smashing message and crash, for if the storage for that variable is at the beginning (top) of the function's stack frame, then overrunning its bounds will indeed smash the stack.
Other things not to like:

unwarranted use of goto.  I'm not a goto bigot, but in practice, structured flow-control constructs are almost always preferable. And I've never run into a use of goto that I would accept that (i) jumped backward, or (ii) jumped into a loop or conditional from outside.

you're making unneeded trouble and complexity for yourself by trying to determine the message length before you read.  You do not need to do this.  Simply allocate a buffer large enough for most messages, and read into it what you can.  Reallocate and read some more if you fill the read buffer without getting a complete message.  It will not be a problem if an incoming message is smaller than the buffer -- you'll just get a short read.

you probably need to be more sophisticated about recognizing the end of a message.  With the current code, if ever you fail to clear all the bytes of one message from the receive buffer before some or all of another message lands there, you will not properly recognize the end of the first.



Thank you so much man, changing data type to int fixed it. I will try to fix the goto, I don't like it either tbh. Also, I already have some code verifying the end of a message outside the read_socket_raw function. About the length, I just think this is the most elegant solution, because I don't have a set message length limit and I don't want to do so.
Marking as solved. Thank you.
